# Does "capello" (it.) ever mean "hat" (Eng.)?

Tags: word-meaning

Many (all that I looked) English-Italian dictionaries give a transaltion for "*a hat*" as "*capello*". However, looking for this word the other way around never shows "hat" as one of the translations of the word "*capello*". Two Italian dictionaries I have looked in also don't mention any kind of head covering as a meaning of "*capello*" ([one](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=capello), [two](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/capello.php)).

Does "*capello*" ever mean any kind of head covering at all? If yes, if this a special kind of hat?

Comment: Would you please mention at least a single En-It dictionary that gives *capello* as a translation for *hat*? Are you sure they don't say *cappello*?

Comment: Oh my, you're right! I didn't pay attention to it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an actual question, but a mistake of the OP.

Comment: Mistaking “consonanti doppie” is frequent in foreigners; on Math.SE we can see quite often “Riccati” (a mathematician active in the 18th century) misspelled as “Ricatti” (blackmail).

Comment: Technically speaking *capello* does mean a head covering, of some sort ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for ***[cappello](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/C/cappello.php)*** meaning ***hat***.

***[Capello](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/C/capello.php)***, note one single "***p***", means hair.